# How can I open with Safari an html file in dropbox on my iOS device

Tags: ios, safari, dropbox

I have a simple html file with all my links that I share between all my devices.
I can see and open the file from within the Dropbox application but cannot seem to figure out, how to open it from Safari and add it to my favorites.

Comment: Why not use iCloud sync for your bookmarks?  FireFox and Edge (chromium engine) all support bookmark synchronization. Chrome, too, but I avoid using Google products

Comment: Would you consider 3rd party solutions? See this page at [MakeUseOf](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-great-ways-sync-bookmarks-favorites-computers-phones/#sync-your-bookmarks-across-all-platforms) for some plugin- and extension- based bookmark synchronizers. I cannot vouch for any of them, so YMMV. I need to use the Googles for work, so I keep Chrome browsers synched on my Macs, iPhone and iPads. So handy to have all my links available.

Comment: I've been using a simple HTML file to save frequently accessed websites since Netscape Navigator was version 3. I am not aware of anything that will let you open a local file on iOS. However I just have that HTML file on my personal blog and have a bookmark on my iPhone pointed to it. Of course, that would mean the solution is "having a blog." So not a solution for everyone... ;-)